# Alterar dominio principal de um site na digitalocean

Tags: servidor

Tenho um site wordpress rodando normalmente no dominio www.exemplo1.com.br porem quero mudar o dominio para www.exemplo2.com.br  ja configurei o dns e tudo mais, porem a pasta que fica os arquivos do site la no servidor `(/var/www/exemplo1.com.br/public_html/)` tem o nome de exemplo1.com.br, preciso alterar o nome dessa pasta para exemplo2.com.br? Isso não vai prejudicar meu site?

Obs>: Configurei o server com o `easyengine`.

obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Vai dar problemas, o WP guarda as configurações do seu dominio dentro da base de dados.

1 - Antes de tudo, faça um backup.

2 - Entra no MySql,

3 - Procura "siteurl" em wp_options e substitua o endereço.

Veja se resolve.

Comment: Esse link pode te ajudar;

https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Mudando_o_URL_do_Site

Comment: Sim sim essa parte eu sei consigo mudar, o problema que configurei o server usando o easyengine  entao ele foi todo configurado com o exemplo1.com.br    a parte de trocar no wordpress blz mas e o nome da pasta aonde esta o arquivo por exemplo q esta com nome de exemplo1.com.br

Answer (score 0):

Não dá para fazer apenas renomeando. Será necessário modificar também o banco de dados do EasyEngine.

A maneira mais simples que eu vejo de resolver este problema seria:

1. Criar um novo site com o seu novo domínio;
2. `wp export` no primeiro domínio, para gerar um XML;
3. `wp import` no domínio novo, para importar o conteúdo;
4. copiar os plugins e o tema do blog antigo para o novo;
5. revisar as configurações do site novo;
6. `ee site delete` para acabar com o site antigo, quando tiver certeza de que está tudo certo.

Outra coisa em que pensei depois:

1. `ee site create` para criar o novo domínio;
2. `ee site info` para descobrir os dados do banco de dados do site original;
3. o mesmo acima para o site novo;
4. `mysqldump banco_de_dados > banco.sql` do banco de dados original;
5. `mysql banco_novo < banco.sql` para restaurar o banco de dados inteiro do site original no site novo;
6. `cd /var/www/sitenovo/htdocs ; wp search-replace dominio-antigo dominio-novo` para fazer os ajustes no banco de dados;
7. `rsync` do `wp-content` do site original para o do site novo;
8. conferir tudo e apagar o site original.